# keyboard not working but mouse is working

Tags: keyboard

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and I made an upgrade last time and asked me to reboot the laptop. after restarting the laptop, I realized that my keyboard is not working at all [I am currently typing from on screen keyboard].

I tried to do sudo update and also sudo upgrade. Moreover, I tried to log in as guest to see if the keyboard is working; however, it is still not working.

is there solution to make the keyboard work again as it was before.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've a dell xps 15z laptop and faced the same problem (with 12.04, I didn't do fresh install of 14.04). The recipe is found on [ubuntu hardware web-site](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Laptops/Dell/XPS/15z) -- You could try this recipe, or search for You hardware on this web-site.

So keyboard didn't work. I opened

- vitual keyboard
- konsole

Then typed in konsole:

```
sudo kate /etc/default/grub
```

in there I had to change the following line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq quiet splash"
```

saved it, and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

On reboot keyboard worked.

Comment: This worked for me after my Apple keyboard just stopped working suddenly on specific ports. Reboot was essential. I am on 16.04.